# Why would SHIELD play a game from 1941 on the radio?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, shield, captain-america-the-first-avenger

At the end of Captain America: The First Avenger, Cap wakes up in a "Recovery Room" with an Agent Carter lookalike and all of the good ol' 1945 comforts, complete with a handheld radio playing a baseball game (If I remember correctly, it involved the Dodgers). The only problem was that Cap had already seen that game; it was from 1941, 4 years prior to his crash. The question is, why would SHIELD (Which obviously set up the whole scene) play a game from an earlier time, when they could have played a game from after the crash?

Comment: Since the announcer didn't outright state it was 1941, they likely assumed Steve wouldn't notice the difference in the short amount of time between waking up and them explaining the situation to him.

Comment: @Rogue Jedi I know, but why take the risk of him recognizing the game in the first place? It seemed to me like an unnecessary risk for such an advanced organization...

Comment: Maybe Hydra switched the audio files ;)

Comment: I just assumed they only had audio from a few famous games left after 60+ years

Comment: @KutuluMike - My interpretation is that it was supposed to be a bit of set-dressing that would last a few minutes after Steve regained consciousness while they went and got someone to talk to him. The fact that the background behind the window was a projection would also have been immediately obvious to someone with his enhanced senses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is based upon the premise that the audio track was intended to be circa 1945 and something that he had not heard before. If that was the case, then just about any post-1945 baseball game (with appropriate beer/hotdog/brylcreem commercials) would do.

I would postulate that his surroundings were designed to reduce culture shock and make him feel comfortable if and when he awoke but not intentionally designed to deceive. The audio track playing on a loop through the period-accurate radio was a baseball game they *knew* he was familiar with and had been chosen for that very reason.

This would parallel reading passages of a favourite book to a coma patient for therapeutic reasons.

Comment: Playing something he heard before on a radio (or what looks like one) is likely to be so he wouldn't think time has passed.

Answer (score 6):

SHIELD likely could not predict the exact moment at which Cap would awaken.  Thus, they put him in a period-appropriate room, and part of that included the radio.

They probably had the radio playing the whole time he was in the room, not just right before he woke up.  Given the amount of time it would take for him to awaken, they likely provided a large number of audio files.  Someone who was told to select audio files appropriate to his era must have gotten a bit sloppy with the dates.

Creating a convincing illusion is HARD.  They screwed up only in a single, relatively minor way.  Yes, they could have avoided it if they had paid more attention, but they had no way to know that was an area they'd have to pay more attention to.  They simply didn't have (or use) enough resources to make it a 100% perfect illusion.

Answer (score -1):

Over 60 years have passed since he was frozen, they didn't know where he fell or if he survived, since finding him, they had days, maybe even hours to arrange that room, live recordings from that time are not so common, and not a lot of them are clean enough to pass as live radio, audio cleanup takes time and they probably had to make a large enough loop so it will not be immediately identifiable as a loop recording, as that was a radio.
It could also be a mislabeled recording or a mistake of the person creating the loop.

Comment: Lotsa guesswork here and no evidence to back it up